# Auto click a link in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am working in ruby on rails,

I want to auto click on

```
<%= link_to 'Referesh', :onclick => 'window.opener.location.reload(true)' %>
```

when I submit the form by

```
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
```

My question is how I can perform auto clicking on link_to when I submit the form by f.submit.
Both are in the same form.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you can either submit the form or click the link--can't do both, unless you submit the form via Ajax.

Comment: this is actually not a direct ruby on rails question, since you want to do something between the rails stages. Rails renders your view, and your server presents it to you. Until a new page is loaded, there isn't much for rails to do (unless there are some background jobs)

so what you want to do is using javascript, probably, like dave said in combination with an ajax request. if you could elaborate your context a little bit more, we could help in more detail.

Comment: Why do you want to click the link? Just call the refresh logic from your submit logic.

Comment: Seems like @hmsulehri is trying to refresh page after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why/what you want to do.. the question is not clear. However, you can override the onsubmit() and do something there.

If you're using JQuery, you can trigger the click event on a link with something like this:

```
$("a#my_link").trigger('click');
```

If you're using Prototype, you should include [event.simulate.js](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js)

I've used this several times and it works like a charm. It allows you to manually trigger native events, such as click or hover:

```
$('a#my_link').simulate('click');
```